# Send APDU commands to simcard through SIM900 module

Tags: apdu, sim900

Is that possible to send APDU commands (as done in javacard terminals) to a sim card inserted into a Sim900 module?

How can one do that? Is there any reference for setup and APDU commands instruction?

### Appendix A:

In [this](https://www.telit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Telit_AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r24_B.pdf) document, I found that there are AT commands to open/close logical channels (AT+CCHO / AT+CCHC). Is that possible to send ADPUs through these logical channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,AT+CCHO open a logical channel for your SIM card app, and then you send APDU to the app with AT+CGLA.Finally AT+CCHC close the channel to the app.

That means you need write a SIM card app and download it to the SIM CARD using a card reader.